# Hangfire Error on startup

Tags: owin, hangfire

I had hangfire working well for sometime and then I tried to rollback to a previous version that supported .net 4.5.1 and then I went back to .net 4.6.1 and re-upgraded hangfire to 1.6.14 with Owin 3.1.  I've reset all my code/nuget references, etc to 1.6.14 and deleted all of the tables so it would recreate them and I'm still getting this error:

'hangfire.dashboard.dashboardmiddleware' does not have a constructor taking 5 arguments.

I'm using owin 3.1 and this happens when using this code:

```
    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyWebApplication.Startup))]
    namespace MyWebApplication
    {
    public class Startup
    {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
            app.UseHangfire(config =>
            {
                  config.UseSqlServerStorage(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QueueConnection"].ConnectionString);
                  config.UseServer();
            });
    }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use hangfire like this:

```
JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage(constr);
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
   var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 5 };
        app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```